# Extract specific string between two strings and list the required content

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

how to find the block name in which the string available ?

server.conf file

```
server_pool odd {
    0:server1:yes:profile_server1:192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2;
    1:server3:yes:profile_server3:192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6;
}

server_pool even {
    0:server2:yes:profile_server2:192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4;
    1:server4:yes:profile_server4:192.168.1.7,192.168.1.8;
}

#server_pool even {
#    0:server1:yes:profile_server1:192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2;
#    1:server3:yes:profile_server3:192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6;
#}
```

Notes:-

1. "server_pool" is a static string
2. "pool_name" can be any string without spaces
3. "if a line has # in it ignore it

Requirement

1. Need to find the "pool_name" by the provided server hostname as input i.e server{1,2,3,} and store it in a variable

for example

if need to find server1 belongs to which block/ stanza. in the given use case it belongs to odd, so store variable as POOLNAME=odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -oP '^server\s\K[^ ]+|^[^#]\s+\d+:\K[^:]+' inputfile
pool0
server1
server2
pool1
server3
server4
```

Comment: how to print pool0, pool1 along with static string "server" on the beginning of the same line

Comment: Please add exact sample input to get your desired result, because this solution worked on initially provided sample input.

Comment: I don't know may be RavinderSingh13 marked it as duplicate question but whereas i don't think it is a duplicate question. it is two different requirements

Comment: @asokan how that is related to accepting the answer!! Ravindra will always act fair since you clarified your question is not getting duplicated. Please do not accept answers to please anyone, if you think it really helped you and you are going to use the code in your program then accept and upvote. . Although its up to you. Its about good better best, not pleasing. Ending the discussion, do not reply.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'[: ]+' '/}/{p=0}/^#|}/||!NF{next}/pool[0-9]+[ \t]+?{/{if(h)print "";p=1;print $2;next}p{print $3;h=1}' file
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk -F'[: ]+' '
               # if line contains }, set variable p=0

                      /}/{ 
                            p=0;
                         }

              # If line start with #, closing }, or empty line, skip

            /^#|}/ || !NF{ 
                            next 
                          }

               # if line contains pool[0-9]+ can be space or tab and then {, 
               # if variable h was set before
               # print newline,
               # set variable p =1, print 2nd field, go to next line

    /pool[0-9]+[ \t]+?{/{ 
                            if(h)print "";
                            p=1;
                            print $2;
                            next
                        }

               # as long as p is set,
               # print 3rd field from such record, 
               # h =1, to have newline char when awk finds news pool

                       p{
                            print $3;
                            h=1
                        }
              ' file
```

**Here is Test results:**

Input:

```
$ cat file
server pool0 {
        0:server1:yes:profile_server1:192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2;
        1:server2:yes:profile_server2:192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4;
}

server pool1 {
        0:server3:yes:profile_server3:192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6;
        1:server4:yes:profile_server4:192.168.1.7,192.168.1.8;
}

#server pool2 {
#        0:server5:yes:profile_server5:192.168.1.9,192.168.1.10;
#        1:server6:yes:profile_server6:192.168.1.11,192.168.1.12;
#}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -F'[: ]+' '/\}/{p=0}/^#|\}/||!NF{next}/pool[0-9]+[ \t]+?\{/{if(h)print "";p=1;print $2;next}p{print $3;h=1}' file
pool0
server1
server2

pool1
server3
server4
```

Comment: There are other blocks also in the file, for example
client client_pool {
        0:server3:yes:profile_server3:192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6;
        1:server4:yes:profile_server4:192.168.1.7,192.168.1.8;
}
it picks that too

Comment: @asokan, as I requested already, kindly show us the sample Input and expected output in your post with code tags.

Comment: @asokan: I see its working with new input sample which you updated

Answer (score 0):

Following awk may help you in same.

```
awk -F' +|:' '/^$/{flag="";next} /^server pool/{print $2;flag=1;next} flag && NF && !/}/{print $3}' Input_file
```

**EDIT:** If your pool block you could have many other entries other than servers then I have added an additional check for it, try it and let me know then.

```
awk -F' +|:' '/^$/{flag="";next} /^server pool/{print $2;flag=1;next} flag && NF && !/}/ && $3~/server/{print $3}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT2:*** Showing OP that code is providing the expected output by OP only.

```
awk -F' +|:' '/^$/{flag="";next} /^server pool/{print $2;flag=1;next} flag && NF && !/}/ && $3~/server/{print $3}' Input_file
pool0
server1
server2
pool1
server3
server4
```

Comment: i forgot to mention there are different group names in the file, like "server" there are "client" "disks", I need only "server"

Comment: @asokan, Above will only look for servers? Are you saying inside block you have clients/disks etc? could you please let me know more details on where it is not working?

Comment: There are different stanzas in the file, it also list those 

clients
cn01
cn02
main
=
=

and also it prints "=" in some places

Comment: @asokan, could you please check my EDIT answer, also it is not clear to me, could you please add sample Input and expected output again(with this new condition) in your post with code tags and let us know then.

Comment: @asokan, I just checked my command with your new edited data and it shows same output which you are expecting, see my EDIT2 now.

Comment: grep -oP '^server\s\K[^ ]+|^[^#]\s+\d+:\K[^:]+' inputfile

the above given solution worked out for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155891/discussion-between-asokan-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 0):

GRPNAME="server pool0 {"
GRPNAME=${GRPNAME%{*}; GRPNAME=${GRPNAME#*\ }

```
where:
${GRPNAME%\{*} = delete everyting from end ("%") until 1st "{*"; the "\" is an escape character
${GRPNAME#*\ } = delete everything from beginning ("#")and stop after 1st space; ; the "\" is an escape character
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -o "^server pool[0-9]|^[^#][ ]+[0-9]:server[0-9]" file.txt | cut -d ':' -f2 | sed 's/\(server pool[1-9]\)/\n\1/g'
```

**Output**

```
server pool0
server1
server2

server pool1
server3
server4
```

**Note**

I suppossed that pool are always starting by 0 and that you can not have pool with an index > 9. If that's not the case you can change, for example `[0-9]` to `[0-9]{1,2}` to accept number between -1 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^(server \S+).*/{s//\1/p;:a;n;s/^(([^:]*):){2}.*/\2/p;ta}' file
```

Focus on lines that begin `server` and extract the first two words from such lines. From subsequent lines, extract the second field (using `:` as a separator) until a failure to match occurs.