# how to find the block name in which the string available?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

how to find the block name in which the string available ?

stanza example

```
server_pool pool_name {
    0:hostname:yes/no:profile:ip_address
    1:hostname:yes/no:profile:ip_address
    2:hostname:yes/no:profile:ip_address
    .:hostname:yes/no:profile:ip_address
    .:hostname:yes/no:profile:ip_address
    N:hostname:yes/no:profile:ip_address
}
```

server.conf file

```
server_pool odd {
    0:server1:yes:profile_server1:192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2;
    1:server3:yes:profile_server3:192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6;
}

server_pool even {
    0:server2:yes:profile_server2:192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4;
    1:server4:yes:profile_server4:192.168.1.7,192.168.1.8;
}

#server_pool even {
#    0:server1:yes:profile_server1:192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2;
#    1:server3:yes:profile_server3:192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6;
#}
```

Notes:-

1. "server_pool" is a static string
2. "pool_name" can be any string without spaces
3. "if a line has # in it ignore it

Requirement

when a hostname is provided as input to server.conf file then I am expecting a output of the pool_name that it belongs to.

for example

server.conf < server1
then it should return
"odd"

server.conf < server2
then it should return
"even"

Comment: Could you post some expected output? That would be helpful.

Comment: Please help others with sample output you want.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have accepted the answer from PS on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558708/extract-specific-string-between-two-strings-and-list-the-required-content/46558823#46558708.  this is an different help required. thanks for the understanding

Comment: @asokan, this new question is still NOT clear, please show expected output in code tags with all the conditions.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Output expected is the "pool_name" that server belongs too. for example 1:- if server1 [it is a hostname] is given as input then it should reurn "odd"

for example 2:- if server2 is given as input then it should reurn "even"

Comment: @asokan, gotcha, provided solution for same now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract specific string between two strings and list the required content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558708/extract-specific-string-between-two-strings-and-list-the-required-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following script and let me know if this helps you. As per your need this script will require to have an argument should be given to it. Which will be then matched from your Input_file and according to that Pool name will be printed.

```
cat script.ksh
var=$1
awk -v VAR="$var" -F' +|:' '/^}/{flag=""} /^server_pool/{flag=1;pool=$2;;next} flag && $0 ~ VAR{print pool}' Input_file
```

Following is the output when I run it.

```
./script.ksh server1
odd
```

Comment: @asokan, glad that it helped you. You could upvote an answer which looks to helpful to you too, along with selecting an answer as correct one. Keep learning and keep sharing knowledge, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS=  '!/^#/&&/server2/{print $2}' input
even
awk -v RS=  '!/^#/&&/server1/{print $2}' input
odd
```

Explanation: Here two checks are done, first is to weed out the records starting with comments and the records containing `serverX` , where X is the number of the server. `RS` is set to blank to make awk to take paras as single record.

You can use `bash` variable as input using following where host is a variable whose value is set:

```
awk -v RS=  -v host=server1 '!/^#/&& $0 ~ host{print $2}'
```

Comment: it works, just one modification required. don't weed out all the records that starting with comments. only records that starts with server_pool

Comment: then change `!/^#/` to `!/^server_pool/` that should work.

Comment: since this question is marked as duplicate, couldn't give you right answer twice. but you helped me a lot.

Comment: @asokan there is no such limitation in stackoverflow. Also your question is not yet duplicated.